# How to create node of particular content type from webform results?

Tags: drupal-6, webforms, drupal-7, content-type

Is it possible to configure a webform to create nodes of a specific content type from the submitted data?  Assume that the fields from the webform would directly match the fields on the content type.

Comment: are you asking if anyone knows how to created a node with the same values as a webform submission?

Comment: yes i need help to create node of webform submmission result.

Comment: I don't believe there's an automatic or easy way to this.  It might be possible with the rules module and tokens, or it is definitely possible with a custom module.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Declare a new StdObj
$node = new StdObj();

//Set the type
$node->type='your_content_type';

//Set the Title
$node->title='title';

//Set the body
$node->body = 'body';

//Set other content fields
$node->field_name[0]['value'];

//Finally use functions to save, submit, and insert the node
$node = node_save($node);
node_submit($node);
content_insert($node);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a content type with the same fields as the webform and grant anonymous users permission to creates nodes of that content type.